# Disable option Grid Orbeon

Tags: forms, orbeon, runner

I am using a repeated grid, as follows:

[image: (image)]

Is it possible to disable the options in the red square, and only keep the button in the green square for users to add new items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either:

- Use [custom CSS](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner.html#adding-your-own-css) to hide that dropdown menu.
- Set the [`oxf.xforms.xbl.fr.grid.repeat.appearance.*.*` to `minimal`](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner.html#appearance-of-repeated-grids), and your repeated grid will look as follows:

  [image]